# Javascript chained variable assignments declared inside IIFE gets global visibility?

Tags: javascript, var, iife

Was recently asked what the following JavaScript code would result in and the correct answer confuses me:

```
(function () {
    var a = b = 5;
})();
console.log(b);
```

I would have thought this would print `undefined` but it actually prints `5`.

From my understanding, all variables defined inside IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) should *not* be visible outside its scope. How exactly does the ordering of these variable declarations make `b` visible outside its scope while `a` is not visible outside its scope?

Comment: `b` is globally declared here. `var a, b = 5` would declare both locally but would not assign anything to `a`.

Comment: And another time where `"use strict"` would have prevented all misery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

> ```
> var a = b = 5;
> ```

Is equivalent to:

```
b = 5;
var a = b;
```

not to

```
var b = 5;
var a = b;
```

It creates `b` as a global, and then assigns the value of `b` to `a`.

It is also forbidden in strict mode. Always use strict mode!

```js
"use strict";

(function () {
    var a = b = 5;
})();
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equal to this

```
(function () {
    b = 5;
    var a = b;
})();
console.log(b);
```

If you declare a variable without `var, let or const` it is going to be global and assigned to the `window` object (in browser's JS), so it is accessible from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax to declare several `var`s in one statement is:

```
var a, b;
// or:
var a = 5, b = 5;
```

What you have is the declaration of `var a`, but `b` is part of the value expression and is not affected by `var`, so leaks into the global scope.